# Making everything become gray in Flash

Tags: actionscript-3, flash

I want my entire game to become grayer as the game progresses. How can I do that?
The only solution I came with is to add a tween to every item in my game (the end of the tween being the object with gray color), have an array of all the objects and make all the items from that array slowly advance in frames (a terrible solution of course). I also could just have my entire game inside a movie clip and then make it tween. But I can't (or don't know how to) do that since I am not creating my game straight from Flash professional, but using an engine (the Citrus Engine). Is there some kind of filter which can alter the colors of my entire game? Or another solution? Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As You can see in `Main.as` (https://github.com/alamboley/Citrus-Engine/blob/master/src/Main.as) Main extends `CitrusEngine`,
when You go further You can see that `CitrusEngine` extends `MovieClip` (https://github.com/alamboley/Citrus-Engine/blob/master/libs/com/citrusengine/core/CitrusEngine.as).

As far as I know You can apply filters to MovieClips like so:

```
var matrix:Array = new Array();
matrix = matrix.concat([1,0,0,0,255]);
matrix = matrix.concat([0,1,0,0,0]);
matrix = matrix.concat([0,0,1,0,0]);
matrix = matrix.concat([0,0,0,1,0]);
var colorFilter:ColorMatrixFilter = new ColorMatrixFilter(matrix);

this.filters = [colorFilter];
```

This way You can add Greyscale filter to MovieClip.

Try adding this inside `Main.as`.

As I wrote before this is only a guess, but please give it a try :)

Comment: Worked like a charm - thanks! Can't believe how easy it was. I added it to the GameState instead of the main because Main is only used for the initial construction while the GameState is easier to manipulate as the game runs.

Comment: +1 for the comment, it will help me in the future. I don't know Citrus Engine (not yet ^-^) but I must give it a try.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Greensock's TweenLite/TweenMax and the colorMatrixFilter.

Go to http://www.greensock.com/tweenlite/ scroll down to Plugin Explorer and play with walues to see what suits you best. I imagine 'saturation' is the one you are looking for.

If you do not want to use external library you still can use Flash's ColorMatrixFilter although it might be tricky to set up all the matrices etc.